# Pandas - Keyword count by Category

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to get a count of the most occurring words in my df, grouped by another Columns values:

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Category':['Red','Red','Blue','Yellow','Blue'],'Text':['this is very good ','good','dont like','stop','dont like']})
```

[image]

This is the way that I have counted the keywords in the Text column:

```
from collections import Counter

top_N = 100


stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
# # RegEx for stopwords
RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))
# replace '|'-->' ' and drop all stopwords
words = (df.Text
           .str.lower()
           .replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords], [' ', ''], regex=True)
           .str.cat(sep=' ')
           .split()
)

# generate DF out of Counter
df_top_words = pd.DataFrame(Counter(words).most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')
print(df_top_words)
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

However this just generates a list of all of the words in the data frame, what I am after is something along the lines of this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `words` statement finds the words that you care about (removing stopwords) in the text of the whole column. We can change that a bit to apply the replacement on each row instead:

```
df["Text"] = (
    df["Text"]
    .str.lower()
    .replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords], [' ', ''], regex=True)
    .str.strip()
    # .str.cat(sep=' ')
    .str.split()  # Previously .split()
)
```

Resulting in:

```
  Category          Text
0      Red        [good]
1      Red        [good]
2     Blue  [dont, like]
3   Yellow        [stop]
4     Blue  [dont, like]
```

Now, we can use [`.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then `.groupby` and `.size` to expand each list element to its own row and then count how many times does a word appear in the text of each (original) row:

```
df.explode("Text").groupby(["Category", "Text"]).size()
```

Resulting in:

```
Category  Text
Blue      dont    2
          like    2
Red       good    2
Yellow    stop    1
```

Now, this does not match your output sample because in that sample you're not applying the `.replace` step from the original `words` statement (now used to calculate the new value of the "Text" column). If you wanted that result, you just have to comment out that `.replace` line (but I guess that's the whole point of this question)